# Theories of Arbitrary Morley Rank

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose that you have a language $L$. I can show that theories like DLO, or any unstable theory for that matter, has Morley Rank $\infty$. 
I can also show that $REI_\alpha$ has Morley rank $\infty$, when $\alpha{\geq}{\omega}$ which I had initially thought to have Morley rank $\alpha$ regardless of the value of $\alpha$. I also know that the Morley rank is $<\infty$ when the theory is $\omega$-stable, at least when the language is countable.

My questions are:

1) Given $L$ is countable, what is a family of theories $T_{\alpha}$ such that the Morley rank of $T_\alpha$ is $\alpha$?

2) Assuming that that the answer to 1) is in the negative, is there an example, or a a family of examples if you remove the cardinality restrictions on $L$ (i.e. For each $\alpha$, a language $L_{\alpha}$ and a theory $T_{\alpha}$ s.t. the Morley rank of $T_{\alpha}$ is $\alpha$)?

Comment: Firstly, superstable does not imply Morley rank $< \infty$. $\omega$-stable does and is actually equivalent to Morley rank $< \infty$ for countable languages. Also for countable $\omega$-stable theories, Morley rank must be countable. This essentially follows from the fact that it equals to the Cantor Bendixson rank in the countable space $S(M)$ for an $\omega$-saturated $M$.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: Oops. That's correct. Sorry. I have adjusted the question.

Comment: The paper "The transcendental rank of a theory" of Lachlan is related to your question. The notion $\alpha_T$ is a little different to the Morley rank of $T$. But my impression is that every countable ordinal can be a Morley rank of some countable theory.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: I will look at the paper. Thank you!